# Program taking too long for large input

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, time-complexity, integer-overflow

I am using an equation in which we have to find the maximum value that *x* can take given the value of *b*. Both *x* and *b* can take only nonnegative integer values. The equation is:

```
x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1≤b
```

I have written the following code(apparently dumb) to solve it:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<climits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned long long b,x=0;
    cout<<"hey bro, value of b:";
    cin>>b;
    while(x++<b)
        if(x*x*x*x+x*x*x+x*x+x+1>b)
        break;
    if(b==0)
    cout<<"Sorry,no value of x satisfies the inequality"<<endl;
    else
    cout<<"max value of x:"<<x-1<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The above code works fine upto `b=LONG_MAX` but after for `b=LONG_LONG_MAX` or `b=ULLONG_MAX`, it starts taking forever. How can I solve this problem so that it works fine for **at most** `b=ULLONG_MAX`?

Comment: `LONG_LONG_MAX` is approximately *4 billion times* more than `LONG_MAX`. `LONG_LONG_MAX` nanoseconds is almost 300 years.

Comment: (After making good use of IVlad's answer,) check the code generated to see if it uses 1+x(1+x(1+x(1+x))).

Answer (score 4):

If for `x = m`, the inequality holds, then it also holds for all integers `< m`. If it doesn't hold  for `m`, then it doesn't hold for any integer `> m`. What algorithm does this suggest?

If you want to spoil yourself, click [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) for the algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

This is not just an optimization issue. (For optimization, see IVlad's answer). It is also a correctness issue. With very large values, the expression causes integer overflow: to put it simply, it wraps around from ULLONG_MAX back to zero, and your loop carries on having not detected this. You need to build overflow detection in your code.

Comment: This is the actual problem in my opinion.How to solve the overflow problem?

Comment: @chanzerre [`__int128`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html) can help you over the overflow of `x*x` but for `x*x*x*x` you need an **256-bit type** which is not available right now and the only way is a bigint library. But solving all the overflow problems still not help you as it still takes centuries to finish. What you need is a new and correct algorithm

Comment: @chanzerre, I've updated my answer, there are two solutions which solves overflow problem: cross-platform (with one more operation before any computation) and with hardcoding of maximal allowed `x` (i.e. with dependence of current machine).

Answer (score 2):

**Old answer** (real problem here is not big number of iterations, but integer overflow; please read from 'Update' part; I keep this part here for history of false assumptions):

These values are very big. When your program checks each value from 0 to `LONG_LONG_MAX`, it shold make about `9*10^12` operations, isn't it? For `ULLONG_MAX` we have about `18*10^12` operations. Try to modify this program to see actual speed of processing:

```
while (x++ < b)
{
    if (x % 1000000 == 0)
        cout << " current x: " << x << endl;
    if (x*x*x*x+x*x*x+x*x+x+1>b)
        break;
}
```

So, you need to optimize this algorithm (i.e. reduce number of iterations): since your function is [monotonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function), you can use [Binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) (see [Bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) too for clarification).

Also there is a possible problem with integer overflow: function `x*x*x*x` for big values `x` will be calculated wrong. Just imagine thay your type is `unsigned char` (1 byte). For example, when your program calculates `250*250*250*250` you expect 3906250000, but in fact you have `3906250000 % 256` (i.e. `16`). So, if `x` is too big, it is possible, that your function will return value `< b` (and it will be strange; theoretically it can brake your optimized algorithm). Good news is that you will not see this problem, if do every check correctly. But for more complex functions you would also need to support long math (for example, use [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) or another implementation).

**Update:** How to avoid overflow risks?

We need to find maximal allowed value of `x` (let's call it `xmax`). Value `x` is allowed if `x*x*x*x+x*x*x+x*x+x+1 < ULLONG_MAX`. So, answer on initial question (about `x*x*x*x+x*x*x+x*x+x+1 < b`) is not bigger than `xmax`. Let's find `xmax` (just solve equation `x*x*x*x+x*x*x+x*x+x+1=ULLONG_MAX` in any system, for example WolframAlpha: anwer is about `65535.75...`, so `xmax==65535`. So, if we check `x` from `0` to `xmax` we will not have overflow problems. Also it is our initial values for binary search algorithm.

Also it means, that we do not need to use binary search algorithm here, because it is enought to check only 65535 values. If `x==65535` is not answer, we have to stop and return answer `65536`.

If we need cross-platform solution without hardcoding of `xmax`, we can use any bigint implementation ([GMP](https://gmplib.org/) or any simpler solution) or implement more accurate multiplication and other operations. Example: if we need to multyply `x` and `y`, we can calculate `z=ULLONG_MAX/x` and compare this value and `y`. If `z<y`, we can't multiply `x` and `y` without overflow.

Comment: +1 for noting the overflow risk. However, I don't see why you downplay the risk. What upperbound do you suggest for the binary search? `x==b` obviously won't work - `x*x*x*x` still overflows. `x=sqrt(sqrt(b))` prevents overflow on the `x*x*x*x` part but might overflow on `+ x*x*x`.

Comment: That's hardcoding the value of ULLONG_MAX, and will fail on systems where `long long` is 128 bits. (Not that weird to imagine: short=16,int=32,long=64,long long=128)

Comment: @MSalters, you are right, we need to be accurate to avoid integer overflow. And if we don't know real size of our data types, it is really hard to fix this problem. Theoretically we can calculate actual `xmax` automatically (we can imagine algorithm for it, which checks correctness of the result; i.e. that for function `f(x)=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1` following expresission is always true: `f(z)<f(z+1)`. Or better and more stable way: to check overflow-flag after each computation. So, we can avoid hardcoding of this value.

Comment: C++ has no method to verify either : there is no overflow flag, and therefore you can't determine if `f(z) > f(z+1)` was caused by unintended overflow. This question is easy to get right 99%, but all the nasty edge cases are tricky.

Comment: @MSalters, we can get an access to overflow flag register in a CPU with Asm, but it is not cross-platform solution (also few CPUs haven't this flag). But we can add one more division for checking of overflow (I've updated my answer).

Answer (score 2):

A really simple observation solves your problem in O(1) time.

Find `k = sqrt(sqrt(b))`

If `k` satisfies your inequality, `k` is your answer. If it does not, `k-1` is your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try finding an upper limit and working down from there.

```
// Find the position of the most significant bit.
int topBitPosition = 0;
while(b >> topBitPosition)
    topBitPosition++;
// Find a rough estimate of b ^ 1/4
unsigned long long x = b >> (topBitPosition - topBitPosition/4);
// Work down from there
while(x*x*x*x+x*x*x+x*x+x+1 > b)
    x--;
cout<<"max value of x:"<<x-1<<endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't let `x` exceed `65535`. If `65535` satisfies the inequality, `65536` will not.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:

First af all you are starting from x=0 and then increasing it which is not the best solution since you are looking for the maximum value and not the first one. 
So for that I would go from an upperbound that can be

x=abs((b)^(1/4))

than decrease from that value, and as soon you find an element <=b you are done.

You can even think in this way:

```
for y=b to 1
   solve(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=y)
   if has an integer solution then return solution
```

See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solving_a_quartic_equation)

This is a super quick answer I hope I didn't write too many stupid things, and sorry I don't know yet how to write math here.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a slightly more optimized version:

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Sorry, no value of x satisfies the inequality" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why? Because `x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1` is unbounded as x approaches positive infinity.  There is no `b` for which your inequality holds.  Computer Science is a subset of math.